# Add background image using Javascript CSS property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background-image

I'm trying to add background image using Javascript CSS property. My code does not work. If I add 'url' directly, it worked.  Is 'weatherImage' variable a problem..?

Javascript

```
var OpenWeatherKey = 'API key';
var locationUrl =  'http://freegeoip.net/json/';

function getLocation(){
    $.ajax({
        url : locationUrl,
        dataType: "json",
        success : function(data){
            var country = data['country_name'];
            var city = data['city'];
            var latitude = data['latitude'];
            var longitude = data['longitude'];
            $('#location').html(city + ', ' + country);
      var Weather = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude +"&APPID=" +OpenWeatherKey;
            getWeather(Weather);

                    }
    });
}
function getWeather(url){
    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(data){
        var weather = data['weather'][0]['main'];
        var temp = data['main']['temp'];
      var icon = data['weather'][0]['icon'];
      var id = data['weather'][0]['id'];
        document.getElementById('icon').src="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + icon + ".png";
        $('#weather').html(weather);
        $('#temp').html(temp);
   // Change F to C, C to F 
  var fahrenheit = Math.floor((temp) * 9/5 - 459.67) + '\xB0F';
  var celsius = Math.floor((temp)- 273.15) + '\xB0C';


  var $tempDisplay = $("#temp");
  $tempDisplay.html(celsius);
  $("#button-f").on('click', function() {
    $tempDisplay.html(fahrenheit);
  });
  $("#button-c").on('click', function() {
    $tempDisplay.html(celsius);
  });

  // change Background image 
  var imagePhoto = {
    thunder: "http://www.tabinotebook.com/wp-

content/uploads/2017/02/jeremy-bishop-72584.jpg",
        rainy: "http://www.tabinotebook.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/lukas-budimaier-131299.jpg",
        cloudy: "http://www.tabinotebook.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/odair-faleco-192489.jpg",
        snow: "http://www.tabinotebook.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/james-padolsey-154227.jpg",
        sunny: "http://www.tabinotebook.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/tomas-salas-81161.jpg",
  }
  var weatherImage = "";
  function selectImage (id){
  if(id >= 200 && id <= 232){
    weatherImage = imagePhoto.thunder;}
  else if (id >= 300 && id <= 531){
     weatherImage = imagePhoto.rainy;}       
  else if (id >= 600 && id <= 622){
     weatherImage = imagePhoto.snow;}   
   else if (id >= 801 && id <= 804){
     weatherImage = imagePhoto.cloudy;}
  else if (id === 800){
     weatherImage = imagePhoto.sunny;}
  else { 
    weatherImage = imagePhoto.cloudy;}
    }

 // we set the background first after the weatherImage has been assigned a value
    // above
$('body').css('background-image','url(' + weatherImage + ')');


 selectImage(800);
        }
        });
    };



getLocation();
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: There is no interpolation of variables in JS as there is  for example in PHP, i.e. "url($weatherImage)" is legal in PHP. So, do as @Cyclonecode has suggested

Comment: Where do you call `selectImage()`?

Comment: I don't think you should share your api key above =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the actual contents of the variable `weatherImage`, right now you're just setting the url to the name of the variable. Try changing your code to:

```
$('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + weatherImage + ')');
```

It is a little hard to tell what is not working since you don't have included the entire script and you also don't show how and where you call `selectImage()`. The following should work though:

```
// change api key to whatever you are using
var OpenWeatherKey = 'your-api-key';
var locationUrl =  'http://freegeoip.net/json/';
var weatherImage = "";
var imagePhoto = {
   thunder: "http://www.tabinotebook.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/jeremy-bishop-72584.jpg",
   rainy: "http://www.tabinotebook.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/lukas-budimaier-131299.jpg",
   cloudy: "http://www.tabinotebook.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/odair-faleco-192489.jpg",
   snow: "http://www.tabinotebook.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/james-padolsey-154227.jpg",
   sunny: "http://www.tabinotebook.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/tomas-salas-81161.jpg"
};

function selectImage (id) {
   if(id >= 200 && id <= 232) {
       weatherImage = imagePhoto.thunder;
   }
   else if (id >= 300 && id <= 531) {
       weatherImage = imagePhoto.rainy;
   }       
   else if (id >= 600 && id <= 622) {
       weatherImage = imagePhoto.snow;
   }   
   else if (id >= 801 && id <= 804) {
      weatherImage = imagePhoto.cloudy;
   }
   else if (id === 800) {
      weatherImage = imagePhoto.sunny;
   }
   else { 
      weatherImage = imagePhoto.cloudy;
   }
   // we set the background first after the weatherImage has been assigned a value
   // above
   $('body').css('background-image','url(' + weatherImage + ')');
}

function getLocation(){
   $.ajax({
       url : locationUrl,
       dataType: "json",
       success : function(data){
           var country = data['country_name'];
           var city = data['city'];
           var latitude = data['latitude'];
           var longitude = data['longitude'];
           $('#location').html(city + ', ' + country);
           var Weather = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude +"&APPID=" +OpenWeatherKey;
           getWeather(Weather);
        }
    });
}

function getWeather(url){
   $.ajax({
       url:url,
       dataType:"json",
       success: function(data) {
          var weather = data['weather'][0]['main'];
          var temp = data['main']['temp'];
          var icon = data['weather'][0]['icon'];
          var id = data['weather'][0]['id'];
          document.getElementById('icon').src= "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + icon + ".png";
          $('#weather').html(weather);
          $('#temp').html(temp);
          // Change F to C, C to F 
          var fahrenheit = Math.floor((temp) * 9/5 - 459.67) + '\xB0F';
          var celsius = Math.floor((temp)- 273.15) + '\xB0C';
          var $tempDisplay = $("#temp");
          $tempDisplay.html(celsius);
          $("#button-f").on('click', function() {
             $tempDisplay.html(fahrenheit);
          });
          $("#button-c").on('click', function() {
             $tempDisplay.html(celsius);
          });

          // select background image based on id
          selectImage(id);
       }
   });
};

getLocation();
```

Comment: $('body').css('background-image','url(' + weatherImage + ')');
 }

Comment: @aaayumi- You must include the whole script and also show where and how you're calling `selectImage()`. A quick solution would be to move the actual background assignment to the bottom om the `selectImage()` function.

Comment: @aaayumi - I added a working example that uses jquery.

Comment: I added selectImage() function.. still does not work. I added a full script as well..

Comment: @aaayumi - I didn't mean that you should call `selectImage(800)` every time it was just added as an example. Start by identing your code properly so it is easier to read and I will have a look again. If you just try my example above you'll see that it works. Try to find where your code is not working by using devtools, firebug or similar and perhaps also use `console.log()` to track down the problem.

Comment: @aaayumi - Also where does the `id` parameter used in `selectImage()` come from? I cannot find it anywhere in your code? My guess would be that you would like to change the background depending on the weather returned from your ajax call to `api.openweathermap.org` - is this correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I want to show the background on the weather ID from ajax call..

Comment: ID parameter comes from   'var id = data['weather'][0]['id']; ' in function getWeather/

Comment: @aaayumi - Your code was lacking some closing `}` - I added a working example above now. Notice that I told you to remove the api key from your question since I guess it's private and you don't want anyone else to use it. In other words you will have to add your api key to `OpenWeatherKey` above.

Comment: Thank you so much. I compared your code and my code. My code was so disorganized..

Comment: @aaayumi - If this answer helped you, you should consider marking it as accepted by clicking the checkmark above.

Comment: Thank you so much!!